# Is the following module projective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, projective-module

Is $\Bbb Z(p^{\infty})$ a projective $\Bbb Z$-module?

Comment: @Fredrik I know that $Q/Z$ is not projective

Comment: @aliakbar: Because $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z\cong\sum\mathbb Z(p^{\infty})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that $\mathbb Z(p^{\infty})$ is an infinite $p$-primary abelian group such that each of its subgroups is finite and cyclic and has the following presentation: $$\mathbb Z(p^{\infty})=\langle x_0,x_1,x_2,...,x_n,...\mid px_0,x_0-px_1,x_1-px_2,...,x_{n-1}-px_n,...\rangle$$ so it is not free abelian with basis $X$. Because if it want to be free then it shold no relation. I think there is an exercise in An Introduction to the theory of groups that says If $G$ wants to have the projective property so it is free abelian. And this exercise shows that the Prüfer group as a $\mathbb Z-$ module can't be projective.

Comment: @ Babak It may for you to explain clearly

Comment: @aliakbar: The prufer group is abelian and it is not free, becuse it has non trivial relations so it is as $\sum\mathbb Z$. This allows us to consider that as a module over $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: I think that what Babak is trying to convey is that a $\,\Bbb Z-$module (aka "abelian group") is projective iff it is a free abelian group, and since the Prufer groups has non-trivial  torsion it can't be free abelian and thus not projective, either.

Comment: @amWhy: I have this cause of you. ;-)